# does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jcreator

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'InvoiceDate' as part of an aggregate function.

```
try {

        Connection con=Conn.getConnection();
        Statement ps=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("Select StoreName, InvoiceDate, sum(Rate*quantity), percent, sum(Tax*Quantity), sum(Amount) from Orders Order By InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo ASC ");

        while(rs.next()){

            v=new Vector();

            v.add(rs.getString(1));
            v.add(converToString(rs.getDate(2)));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(3));
            v.add(rs.getString(4));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(5));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(6));

            mDateWise.addRow(v);
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(c,ex.toString());
    }
```

I just want my record day wise, with sum of rate , tax & amount but differentiate it acc to tax, i.e.5% tax entries of a day are in different rows & 13% tax entries with sum will be a diff. row.

Comment: You should read up on aggregate functions and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: try {
Connection con=Conn.getConnection();
Statement ps=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("Select InvoiceDate, sum(Rate*quantity), percent, sum(Tax*Quantity), sum(Amount) from Orders GROUP BY InvoiceDate");
   
   while(rs.next()){
    v=new Vector();
    
    v.add(converToString(rs.getDate(1)));
    v.add(rs.getDouble(2));
    v.add(rs.getString(3));
    v.add(rs.getDouble(4));
    v.add(rs.getDouble(5));
    
    mDateWise.addRow(v);
   }
   con.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(c,ex.toString());
  }
too few parameters. expected 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be:

```
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("Select StoreName, InvoiceDate, sum(Rate*quantity), [percent], sum(Tax*Quantity), sum(Amount) from Orders Group By InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo, StoreName, [percent]");
```